# $A$ prime in $S$ implies that $\phi^{-1}(A)$ prime in $R$ ; $A$ maximal in $S$ implies that $\phi^{-1}(A)$ maximal in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Suppose $R,S$ are commutative rings with unities. Let $\phi$ be a ring homomorphism mapping $R\to S$ and let $A\subset S$ be an ideal. How can I start the proofs for:
>
> Showing that $A$ prime in $S$ implies that $\phi^{-1}(A)$ prime in $R$
>
> and that
>
> showing that $A$ maximal in $S$ implies that $\phi^{-1}(A)$ maximal in $R$

I feel these questions' proofs will be very similar so that's why they are both listed here under one question.

What I know about these:

By the definition I know that a prime ideal $A$ of $S$ means that if I have $a,b\in S, ab\in A$ then $a\in A$ or $b\in A$.

Also by definition I know that a maximal ideal $A$ in $S$ is a proper ideal such that $A\subset B\subset R$ gives us that $B=A$ or $B=R$ where $B$ is an ideal of $R$.

I also know that since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, the two binary operations are preserved.

If someone could help get me started, it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The second one is not correct unless $\phi$ is surjective (consider for example the inclusion of the integers in the rationals)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Just wondering if i have a mapping $\phi: Z \rightarrow Z$ such that $\phi(a) = 3a$ then isn't it true that 3Z is an ideal of Z but $\phi^{-1}(3Z) = Z$ is not an ideal of Z? What is wrong with my example? Z is ring of integers

Comment: But that is indeed an ideal, just not a maximal one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know that $\phi^{-1}A$ is an ideal of $R$, then to show it is prime we argue as follows:
$$
ab \in \phi^{-1}A \to \phi(ab) \in A \to  \phi(a)\phi(b) \in A \to \phi(a) \in A \lor \phi(b) \in A \\
\to a \in \phi^{-1}A \lor b \in \phi^{-1}A
$$